# nginx redirect loop, index.html

Tags: nginx

This seems ridiculous but I've not found a working answer in over an hour of searching.
When I access "http://oa.wechat.com/screen/index.html", it will cause a 301 redirect loop, like this:

```
"GET /screen/ HTTP/1.1" 301
"GET /screen/index.html/ HTTP/1.1" 301 
"GET /screen/index.html/index.html/ HTTP/1.1" 301 
...
```

nginx verson: 1.5.6
nginx.conf

```
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name oa.wechat.com;

        location ~ ^/screen/ {
            alias /data/screen/static/;
            index index.html;
        }  
    }
```

Could anyone tell me the reason? Thanks very much.

i have checked nginx document. the right usage of 'alias':

```
    # use normal match like this
    location  /i/ {
      alias  /spool/w3/images/;
    }

    # use regex match like this
    location ~ ^/download/(.*)$ {
      alias /home/website/files/$1;
    }
```

the wrong way to use 'alias' is:

```
    location ~ ^/screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
        index index.html;
    }
```

In this case, the request would be considered as a directory request, not file request, which will lead a redirect loop.

Anyway, Thanks Flesh very much!

Comment: I can't really figure out what's wrong, are you sure the 301 isn't generated from your app ?

Comment: from nginx access log, I can see that the request wasn't passed to backend server, just handled by nginx

Comment: I met the same issue today, still don't understand why nginx considered the request as a directory request, could you please explain this more specifically ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's already trying to access `index.html` in that directory because it's the default of nginx's [`index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index). The problem is that you're using the `index` directive within a [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) where it has a special meaning and executes an internal redirect (as documented).

Unless you know what you're doing, set the `index` directive within the [`server` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server). We end up with the following `server` block (be sure to read the comments).

```
server {
    # Both default values and not needed at all!
    #index      index.html;
    #listen     80;
    server_name oa.wechat.com;

    # Do not use regular expressions to match the beginning of a
    # requested URI without protecting it by a regular location!
    location ^~ /screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
    }

}
```

### `location` examples

```
server {

    # Won't work because the /data is considered the new document root and
    # the new location matches the regular expression again.
    location ~ ^/screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
    }

    # Should work because the outer location limits the inner location
    # to start with the real document root (untested)
    location / {
        location ~ ^/screen/ {
            alias /data/screen/static/;
        }
    }

    # Should work as well above reason (untested)
    location / {
        location ~ ^(/screen/) {
            alias /data$1static/;
        }
    }

    # Might work as well because we are using the matching group
    # VERY BAD because we have a regular expression outside any regular location!
    location ~ ^(/screen/) {
        alias /data$1static/;
    }

    # Always works and allows nesting of more directives and is totally save
    location ^~ /screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
    }

}
```

### Weblinks

- [`alias` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)
- [`index` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index)
- [`location` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: it works, no more redirect loop.
But I really want to know why my previous config will cause a 301 loop, could you explain it for me?

Comment: As written in my answer, the `index` directive within a `location` block has a special meaning and will start redirecting indefinitely (well, up to 10 times because nginx is breaking the cascade itself afterwards).

Comment: `location ~ ^/screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
    }`this code will still cause a loop, but `location ^~ /screen/ {
        alias /data/screen/static/;
    }` this works fine. I will be appreciate if you could tell me the big difference

Comment: You're using a regular expression outside of any protecting regular location. That's just bad practice and might cause problems (like you found it here). Either enclose it (e.g. `location / { location ~ ^/screen/ {} }`) or don't use a regular expression (see my answer). Oh and the reason why this is causing the loop is the fact that both locations (`/screen/` and `/data/screen/static/`) contain the `/screen/` part.

Comment: when i changed to `location ~ ^/screen/ { alias /data/abc/static/; }` , it will also cause a loop.

Comment: The above was only an assumption, but as I said, regular expressions outside any protecting regular location block **are very, very bad** so don't even bother to run tests with 'em. Would be nice if you accept the answer if it solved your problem and ask another question if you have further questions (already getting warnings here because we post too many comments).

Answer (score 1):

you should move `^` location modifier from `^/screen/`, then add `^` before `~`, like this:

```
 `location ^~ /screen/ {
     alias /data/screen/static/;
     index index.html;
  }`
```